# How to make vim restore last cursor position for CURRENT buffer?

Tags: vim, neovim

For some reason vim does not save cursor position of current buffer. For instance, if I have 3 buffers (tabs) open

```
foo | bar* | foobar
```

and "bar" is selected, on exit vim saves cursor position to `"` mark for "foo" and "foobar" but not "bar". It is always the current selected buffer before exit, no matter whether there are other buffers or not. Here is an example of how the `~/.local/share/shada/main.shada` file look like right after I close my vim session:

```
  Local mark with timestamp 2019-07-27T21:29:30:
    % Key  Description  Value
    + f    file name    "/home/damage/tmp/foo"
    + n    name         '"'
    + l    line number  10
    + c    column       0

  Local mark with timestamp 2019-07-27T21:29:30:
    % Key  Description  Value
    + f    file name    "/home/damage/tmp/bar"
    + n    name         '"'
    + l    line number  1
    + c    column       0

  Local mark with timestamp 2019-07-27T21:29:30:
    % Key  Description  Value
    + f    file name    "/home/damage/tmp/foobar"
    + n    name         '"'
    + l    line number  20
    + c    column       0
```

Mark `"` for current buffer is always 1. When I force vim to explicitly save cursor position to `"` mark with command `m"`, this information is lost on exit. Have no idea where to start.

```
shada=!,'10,/100,:100,<0,@1,f1,h,s1,%10
```

Comment: Note for readers: shada is an nvim-ism replacing viminfo files. They are similar but different. `shada` controls what is saved, and `f1` means save all marks.

Comment: OP: have you considered filing an issue on neovim’s github?

Comment: I guess I can. I thought I got something wrong with documentation because there is a bunch of settings in `shada` option. Does your vim configuration save the cursor position?

Comment: Yes: see my Dotfiles on github. Im my vimrc, I `set viminfo+=f1`. I then use an autocommand to restore the cursor position (in plugin/lastpos.vim).

Comment: Thank you for the config. My setup also fails with vim, so I will try to test it first with your configuration.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend cloning my whole config. Just copy the relevant lines.

Comment: I meant I should have used your config to fix the whole environment, because there could be something that might broke the feature. Indeed, there was something, but it was not my vimrc file. This was broken because of my session manager plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by session manager I use. More specifically, this line.

```
autocmd VimLeavePre * execute s:isActiveSession() && s:saveSession()
```

I replaced this event with `VimLeave` which is called after `shada` file is written.

```
autocmd VimLeave * execute s:isActiveSession() && s:saveSession()
```

**UPD**: In pursuit of smaller code base I forgot that there is `:n` command which moves the cursor. No matter what result the expression will be evaluated, the cursor will be placed at first line (`:0` works the same as `:1`). So I should write another function or replace it with the following.

```
autocmd VimLeave * if s:isActiveSession() | call s:saveSession() | endif
```